# Adding fields to list unsubscribe page

Tags: civimail

I'd like to collect some feedback from people when they unsubscribe from our mailing lists, but it seems that civiCRM doesn't have a way for me to access the unsubscribe page to add additional custom fields.

Ideally, I'd just like to ask a question like: "Can you tell us more about why you are unsubscribing?" And then display a custom field with either a text box or a radio list of reasons.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm running civi 5.31.0 and Joomla 3.9.23

Comment: nice idea. i think the solution with other CMS would be Drupal (webform) and WP (caldera forms) with the idea being that you would provide a link to this form instead of the unsub link, and that way let folk choose the Public Groups they subscribe to and add other info if you want. ah guess these may not be public groups but i think the approach would still apply. not sure what J! has that has integration in the same way as the other CMS options i mentioned. maybe this hint will help you in terms of which direction to look.

Comment: otherwise it would need to be a custom extension as nothing out of the box offers this